# Trying to recreate linear gradient effect starting from the opposite side

Tags: css, reactjs, linear-gradients

I've been trying to create a triangle that can fit a square in order to expand and move it around. The tip must touch the top of the square and i managed to clear one side of it but in order to make ita triangle with the tip touching the top, I have to do the same on the other side. the problem is even if I change right to left or bottom to top in CSS it always starts on the left side. I am using the Rnd library to expand and move it. Can anyone help, thanks

CSS:

```
  .triangle{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;

        background:  

    linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%)
}
```

here is the react/HTML but might not be needed, I removed anything unnecessary:

```
<Rnd

    style={{backgroundColor:this.props.element === "triangle" ? 'black' : '', border:this.props.id=== this.props.selectedDestinationID ? "solid 2px #ddd" : ""}}
      default={{

        x: 500,
        y: 250,
        width: 60,
        height: 40,
      }}
        bounds="parent">
        <div  onClick={this.selectDestinationsCallBack} class=triangle"
       } style={{ paddingBottom: '0px',}}/>
        </Rnd>
```

Comment: I have created that triangle in another way. Could you check that, it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this triangle will be suited to for your task.
Check this [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/zufh8075/20/)

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0px; 
  height: 0px; 
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out but the width and height must be in percentage for this to work and without the box since Rnd expands thanks to a different prop. This is actually the first shape I tried but without the box